# MKMapView with iOS 8 crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, mapkit

I've a simply view controller with a MKMapView object inside, defined in this way:

Class declaration:

```
@interface GeoViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView* viewMap;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation GeoViewController

- viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
    viewMap = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    MKCoordinateRegion worldRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
    [viewMap setRegion:worldRegion animated:YES];
    viewMap.pitchEnabled = YES;
    viewMap.showsUserLocation = YES;
    viewMap.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:viewMap];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    viewMap.showsUserLocation = NO;
    self.viewMap.delegate = nil;
    [self.viewMap removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)resizeForOrientation:(BOOL)isLandscape withFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super resizeForOrientation:isLandscape withFrame:frame];
    const CGRect fullFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    viewMap.frame = fullFrame;
}

@end
```

First time that I present the view controller works. Then I navigate in my app and if I come back on GeoViewController, crash:

- no message error on console
- main.m is opened and report "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
- on debug navigator (left) I get error report on Thread 1:

  EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int, id)

Now, googling a lot, I can't find a working solution for me:

I also try on viewDidDisappear, but no way

```
 [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
```

Seems crashing for this row:

```
 viewMap.frame = fullFrame;
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

## update

I receive other errors sometime in my test:

**opengl thread conflict detected**

Comment: May be unrelated but since `viewMap` is a property, you should assign it using `self.viewMap = ...` instead of just `viewMap = ...`.  So `viewMap = [[MKMapView alloc] init];` should be `self.viewMap = [[MKMapView alloc] init];`.

Answer (score 4):

I got EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN Errors in

```
EAGLContext_renderbufferStorageFromDrawable(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int, id)
```

aswell, when using a MKMapView.

The Workaround mentioned in this Question: [Adding google maps as subview crashes iOS app with exc_bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264537/adding-google-maps-as-subview-crashes-ios-app-with-exc-bad)
worked for me.

Disableling "GPU Frame Capture" feature in my target schemes did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Product -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Set GPU Frame Capture to Disabled.

[Refetence Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321305/mkmapview-causes-exc-bad-access-when-testing-only)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the one causing the problem

```
[self.viewMap removeFromSuperview];
```

Because if you said that you just navigated back to the view, the viewDidLoad will not be called again. That's why it said that "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS", because your accessing a released object. It crashes on the viewMap.frame = frame because you are accessing the viewMap object which is already released because you remove it from its superView.

Comment: try viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

Comment: or you can just avoid removing the self.viewMap from its superView. Since you are using ARC, self.viewMap will be automatically released when it is not used anymore.

Comment: I already tried both moving on viewWillAppear and removing all code in viewWillDisappear... sailing on high sea!

Comment: can you give me link for this project? i'll try to build it.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidAppear` is called when you push your controller on and also when it has another controller pushed on top. Hence at the moment when you navigate, you are removing the map. The same applies to `viewWillDisappear` as it will be called when you push a new controller on top and also when you finally pop your controller off.

Simply change your functions to add the map when the controller first appears and only do the remove when the controller is being popped from the navigation controller. Something like:

```
- viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 

    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController){
      viewMap = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
      MKCoordinateRegion worldRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
      [viewMap setRegion:worldRegion animated:YES];
      viewMap.pitchEnabled = YES;
      viewMap.showsUserLocation = YES;
      viewMap.delegate = self;
      [self.view addSubview:viewMap];
  }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  // If being popped off, remove the map view. Otherwise
  // leave it alone as we need it when the user navigates
  // back
  if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController){
    viewMap.showsUserLocation = NO;
    self.viewMap.delegate = nil;
    [self.viewMap removeFromSuperview];
  }
}
```

}

This makes sure that the map is present for the duration of the lifetime of the controller which should make sure any access to it is valid at all times.

Comment: @Velthune I noticed you edited your question and moved the map create to `viewDidAppear`. You should also put a guard around that so you only create when the controller is first pushed. See updated answer. If you add/remove all the time there is a period where you may have no map. So create it on first show and remove it when popped off as shown in updated answer.